# Should I Downvote a user's first answer if it is bad?

Tags: discussion, review, down-votes, new-users

I was reviewing first answers today when I came along an answer that didn't answer the question being asked.

The question asked for: *[C++ Naming Conventions for C# Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25033020/c-naming-conventions-for-c-sharp-developers)*
 The answer was about C# naming conventions.

I wondered what is the right thing to do in this case?
I left a comment explaining that it is not an answer to the question being asked. But should I also down-vote the answer or is it ok to leave it this way?

The answer is definitely *not useful*, but should we hold back down-voting new users trying to given a good answer and possibly discourage them at their first attempt?

Or should we teach them to read the question thoroughly and give good answers, by down-voting the answer?

Comment: Consider that **not** downvoting such an answer sends the signal that such answers are OK.

Comment: Well I left a comment too explain it didn't answer the question asked. So that way I think I send a signal that the answer was not OK. I was mainly considered if it's a good thing to down-vote the answer as well.

Comment: What happens when the comment is deleted? What happens to readers who don't see/read the comment?

Comment: I see, that's why I ask the question, because I wasn't sure. So the appropriate thing would be too leave a comment and down-vote the answer?

Comment: It might seem a bit impolite, I suppose. But also, it's impossible for any users reputation to go below +1 so in that sense you're not doing them any harm downvoting the post (unless they have since earned rep elsewhere).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't matter if the answer is from a new poster.

It doesn't matter if it is their very first post.

What matters is the contents of the post - is it a good, useful, correct answer? Is it a bad, lacking, incorrect answer?

Downvoting tells the poster that the community finds the answer lacking - which it does.

Not downvoting a bad answer sends the signal that bad questions are OK.

It is also a signal to readers that the answer is not good - leaving without a downvote doesn't make it as clear (and commenting doesn't help those who don't read them).

With a score of -3, such an answer gets grey and more difficult to read.

It is best to correct bad behaviour as soon as it starts, before bad habits get embedded.